# Could I have some suggestions on data-mining tasks please

Tags: artificial-intelligence, data-mining

Now I need to create a data-mining task of my own.I already talked to some people,the most popular ideas would be price prediction or sport result prediction,which I think there are already plenty of people implementing them.
So could anyone give me some real-life ideas please that you found data-mining may be of use,like predicting what the customer would like to buy based on what they already purchased in a supermarket.
Any idea would be welcomed,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found data mining useful when conducting link-click analysis on websites. This information was used to optimize the user-experience by fine-tuning the most appriciated navigation through the site.

It related to very-specific links and 'classes' of links such as "small item description" and "large item title"

Answer (score 1):

Finding a source of data that can be easily parsed is key, there are quite a few cool data sets out there, check out [statlib](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/) for a few.  One of the more popular data mining applications these days is visualization.  You can take a large (but not too large) dataset where each element is related to each other in some way and use dimensionality reduction algorithms to visualize it.  Algorithms like multi-dimensional scaling (MDS), ISOMap, maximum variance unfolding (MVU), and structure preserving embedding can create 2D (or 3D) representations of the data.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning#Applications